# Getting Premature end of file when building an XML object from a URL

Tags: java, xml, scala, sax

I'm trying to run the following code `val podcastXml = XML.load(new URL(feed))` where the feed in question is https://fourfingerdiscount.podbean.com/feed/

I'm able to load the feed in my browser fine, but I'm getting an
`error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.`
 when I try to run that code against it.

Interestingly enough, when I try to `curl` the feed URL in my browser, it's empty.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I feel like there's a config option that I'm somehow missing.

Also worth mentioning, some of the feeds work fine such as http://maximumfun.org/feeds/are.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading from HTTPS URLs is not so straight as with this `new URL(feed)`. It doesn't get the desired XML contents so easily, but rather an empty response and so the `SAXParseException`.

However the data can be retrieved, one of the ways is the old `HttpsUrlConnection`. But there are also a number of wrapper libs allowing to facilitate it, for example [scalaj-http](https://github.com/scalaj/scalaj-http). With it, you can proceed as follows:

```
import scalaj.http.Http

val url = "https://fourfingerdiscount.podbean.com/feed/"
val xml = Http(url).execute(XML.load).body
// xml is a parsed scala.xml.Elem with the contents you were looking for
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you.